# command "update composer" change my parameter.yml

Tags: symfony, composer-php

When i use :

```
php ../composer.phar update
```

**parameter.yml** file is modified!!

Are there any option to keep own parameter.yml file?

My parameter.yml :

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_driver2: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_host2: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_port2: null
database_name: bissap_forum
database_name2: symfony
database_user: root
database_user2: root
database_password: seb666
database_password2: seb666
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_transport2: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_host2: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_user2: null
mailer_password: null
mailer_password2: null
locale: en
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

And after update composer
parameter.yml :

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: bissap_forum
database_user: root
database_password: seb666
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

I don't understand...

Comment: what are you mean under modified? you mean it remove all custom parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think removing `"Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"` from composer.json can help you, or you can try to add this lines to composer.json:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "keep-outdated": true
        }
    }
}
```

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler/blob/master/README.md).

**EDIT:** This answer is not about the **best practices**, it answers the question just as is.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you have not declared your custom parameters in the `app/config/parameters.yml.dist` file.

In the [Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#canonical-parameters) is recommended to use the file `app/config/parameters.yml.dist` to house all the custom parameters, because every time symfony2 updates, it compares those 2 files and ask you about in case you are reinstalling or installing your app in a different system.

Also if you look in the .gitignore you'll see that `app/config/parameters.yml` is also not uploaded to your version control system.